How to resolve The _AppComponent component is not marked as standalone, but Angular expects to have a standalone component here error?
I'm in the process of migrating my project from Angular 9.1 to Angular 18.1, but I'm encountering the following error during compilation:
NG0907: The _AppComponent component is not marked as standalone, but Angular expects to have a standalone component here. Please make sure the _AppComponent component has the 'standalone: true' flag in the decorator.
Below are the relevant parts of my project:
Here's: main.ts file
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Here's: main.server.ts file
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { config } from './app/app.config.server';

const bootstrap = () => bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, config);

export default bootstrap;

Here's: app.component.ts file
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
      useFactory: (sharedService: SharedService) => sharedService.getDateFormat(),
      deps: [SharedService],
    }
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit { }

Here's: app.module.ts file

AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initConfig,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: InterceptorService,
      multi: true
    },
    CanDeactivateGaurdService

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }

I suspect the issue might be related to the way Angular 18.1 handles bootstrapping, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
SSR is used to

SSR enhances the performance of your application by pre-rendering the HTML on the server, which is particularly beneficial for improving SEO and the initial load time of your application.


If you having a lot of errors and do not really use SSR, you can remove the below lines for angular.json
angular.json
        "server": "src/main.server.ts",
        "prerender": true,
        "ssr": {
          "entry": "server.ts"
        }

For the full guide refer this reddit post.

You are mixing the angular standalone and modular approaches to build an application, you have to choose one of the two, mixing both of them is causing the issue. Since your code looks mostly modular, please try the below code changes.

Try changing your main.server.ts to this.
export { AppServerModule as default } from './app/app.module.server';

Also create a app.module.server.ts like so.
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}

Please find below a generated stackblitz which is modular and SSR enabled for reference.
Stackblitz Demo -> cd test -> npm i -> npm run start

Error after implementing above steps:
`X [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:25:
  3 │ const bindings = require('../build/Release/canvas.node');`


Try removing canvas module and check if error goes away, you need to add canvas module only to app module and not on server side rendering, else just turn off SSR, if you are not using it

How do I turn off SSR and how will it affect the project

@Saurabh updated my answer

The server.ts file in Angular Universal serves as the entry point for server-side rendering (SSR) in an Angular application.
The main.ts file is the entry point for the Angular Application.
You can use a standalone component as "entry point", then you should "boostrap" as
//see that you bootstrap a Component
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, config);

Or you can use a Module as "entry point", then you should "bootstrap" as
//see that you bootstrap a Module
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Your AppComponent is standalone? bootstrap in both (main.ts and main.server.ts) the Component.
Your AppComponent is not standalone? bootstrap in both (main.ts and main.server.ts) the Module witch has [bootstrap]:AppComponent.
